# Can not retrieve documents from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to retrieve all documents from a certain collection 'avtvity' in my Firestore through loadmap() method. I have put the function in my initState() since I want to immediately add the data to my Place which is a class i created to add places. However, the data is not being placed in my 'places' which is a List which makes me question that the loadMap() is not being called.

any idea how to fix it?

here is the code:

```
class PlaceTrackerApp extends StatefulWidget {
   final FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

  PlaceTrackerApp({this.firebaseUser});
  @override
  _PlaceTrackerAppState createState() => _PlaceTrackerAppState();
}

class _PlaceTrackerAppState extends State<PlaceTrackerApp> {
  AppState appState = AppState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.firebaseUser);
    loadMap();    
  }

  static StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> loadMap() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('avtivity').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Loading... Please wait,");
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
            StubData.places.add(new Place(
              id: snapshot.data.documents[i]['id'],
              latLng: snapshot.data.documents[i]['latlng'],
              name: snapshot.data.documents[i]['title'],
              description: snapshot.data.documents[i]['description'],
              starRating: snapshot.data.documents[i]['rating'],
              category: PlaceCategory.activities,
            ));
          }}
          );

}
```

Here is a screenshot of database:
[image]